# immutable.js performance with comparison / equals against nested maps / objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, nested, immutable.js

I've been trying to find some kind of information regarding how immutable.js performs when doing a comparison against deep / nested objects, specifically in terms of big-o notation. Anyone happen to know what it is?

```
objA = Immutable.Map({
  a: 'test',
  b: Immutable.Map({ ... })
});

objB = Immutable.Map({
  a: 'test',
  b: Immutable.Map({ ... })
});

objA.equals(objB); // not clear what the perf is on this
```

Comment: I'd start [here](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/utils/deepEqual.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
const Immutable = require('immutable')

function test (limit, mutate) {
  const rawA = {}
  var i
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    rawA[String(i)] = i
  }
  const rawB = {}
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    rawB[String(i)] = i
  }
  if (mutate) {
    rawB['poison'] = false
  }
  if (Object.keys(rawA).length && Object.keys(rawB).length) {
    if (false) {
      console.log('dummy')
    }
  }
  const a = Immutable.Map(rawA)
  const b = Immutable.Map(rawB)
  const timer = process.hrtime()
  if (a.equals(b)) {
    if (false) {
      console.log('dummy')
    }
  }
  return process.hrtime(timer)
}

const sizes = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10 * 1000, 100 * 1000, 200 * 1000, 400 * 1000, 500 * 1000]
sizes.forEach((limit) => {
  var t1 = 0
  var t2 = 0
  const tries = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  tries.forEach((i) => {
    t1 += test(limit, true)[1]
    t2 += test(limit, false)[1]
  })
console.log(limit,
          t1,
          Math.round(t1 / (tries.length * limit)),
          t2,
          Math.round(t2 / (tries.length * limit)))
})
```

Roughly speaking I'd say that the performance of `.equals` is O(1) when the maps aren't equal, and no worse than O(n) when they are equal.

```
1 313329 62666 579815 115963
10 9617 192 293337 5867
100 10873 22 1900225 3800
1000 17505 4 4998441 1000
10000 32060 1 12044412 241
100000 81504 0 211355401 423
200000 99704 0 543211687 543
400000 133836 0 2231794320 1116
500000 77741 0 2877654681 1151
```